# previous_post_link containing title and 'Previous Post'?

Tags: wordpress

At the moment I have it set up so the it's a span tag above the link that says 'previous post' and 'next post', the problem is even when there isn't a next or previous post, the span tag stays there.

```
<div class="nextprev">
                    <div class="nex1">
                        <span>Previous Post</span>
                        <?php previous_post_link('<strong>%link</strong>'); ?>  
                    </div> <!-- end div nex1 -->


                    <div class="nex2">
                        <span>Next Post</span>
                        <?php next_post_link('<strong>%link</strong>'); ?> 

                    </div> <!-- end div nex1 -->
                </div> <!-- end div nextprev -->
```

How do I put Previous Post inside the php so it only appears when there's a link to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [previous_post_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link) and [next_post_link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/next_post_link) you can allow WordPress to control whether or not the chosen text is displayed.

**Like this:**

```
previous_post_link( '%link', 'Previous Post' );
next_post_link( '%link', 'Next Post' );
```

You can replace **'Previous Post'** and **'Next Post'** text with whatever you want to show up. Also, you can remove the `<span>` tags now. :)

**Edit:**

If you'd like to display the title of the post and **Previous Post** text, **try this:**

```
previous_post_link( '<span>Previous Post</span>%link', '%title' );
```

Comment: The problem with is is that it just says 'previous post', it doesn't show the title of the post.
What I'd like to do is have Previous Post (in a span, for styling) then underneath it the link to the post.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying. I've edited my original answer. Let me know if I've got it right for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Exemple to get url and title for next or previous wp posts:

```
<?php 
$next_link = get_next_post();

//all You can use!
print_r($next_link);

?>
<!-- CUSTOM TITLE -->
<a href="<?php echo $next_link->post_name ?>">Custom Text - Next Post!</a>
<!-- DEFAULT TITLE -->
<a href="<?php echo $next_link->post_name ?>"><?php echo $next_link->post_title ?></a>
```

For previous posts use `get_previous_post()`

Answer (score 0):

This prints out the title of the previous and/or next post and does not print a title or link if a previous/next post doesn't exist. Style the spans whichever way you want.

```
<span class="nav-previous">

<?php previous_post_link( '<span class="meta-nav">Previous Post: ', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>
<?php $prev_post = get_previous_post(); if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>">
<?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?></a></span>
<?php endif; ?>

<span class="nav-next">

<?php next_post_link( '<span class="meta-nav">Next Post: ', 'twentyeleven' ); ?>
<?php $next_post = get_next_post(); if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>">
<?php echo $next_post->post_title; ?></a></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link